# Implementing custom atomic_add() which works with floats

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl

I'm trying to follow the B.12 section of https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html for atomic add, which works with floats. Simply copying and pasting the code from there and changing the types to floats does not work because I can't perform the casting pointer casting from GLOBAL to PRIVATE, required for the atomicCAS operation. To overcome this I decided to use atomic_xchg() because it works with floats, with additional if statement to achieve same functionality as atomicCAS. However, this returns me varying answer when I perform addition on large float vector every time i run the program.

I've tried figuring out how to overcome the explicit conversion from GLOBAL to PRIVATE, but I honestly don't know how to do it so that when I perform addition, the address argument is changed instead of some temp variable.

```
kernel void atomicAdd_2(volatile global float* address, float value)
{
    float old = *address, assumed;

    do {
        assumed = old;
        if (*address == assumed) {
            old = atomic_xchg(address, value + assumed);
        }
        else{
            old = *address;
        }
        // Note: uses integer comparison to avoid hang in case of NaN (since NaN != NaN)
    } while (assumed != old);
}
```

This is my implementation of atomicAdd for floats.

```
kernel void reduce_add(global const float* input, global float* output) {
         float temp = 242.23f;
         atomicAdd_floats(&output[0], temp);
         printf(" %f ", output[0]);

}
```

This is the function where I supply the arguments to the atomicAdd_floats. Note that my input argument contains a vector of floats and output argument is simply where I want to store the result, specifically in the first element of the output vector output[0]; but instead when i printf(" %f ", output[0]); it shows my default initialisation value 0.

[image: Comparison of serially computed ground truth sum against parallel output B]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i'd suggest to remove the "kernel" keyword on the atomicAdd_2 function. "kernel" should be used only on functions you intend to enqueue from the host. 2nd, there are OpenCL implementations of atomic-add-float [on the net.](http://simpleopencl.blogspot.com/2013/05/atomic-operations-and-floats-in-opencl.html)

Then, i'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do. Are you trying to sum a vector and while having the sum in a private variable ? if so, it makes no sense to use atomicAdd. Private memory is always atomic, because it's private. Atomicity is only required for global and local memories because they're shared.
Otherwise i'm not sure why you mention changing the address or the GLOBAL to PRIVATE.

Anyway, the code from the link should work, though it's relatively slow. If the vector to sum is large, you might be better off using a different algorithm (wtth partial sums). Try googling "opencl parallel sum" or such.